# For dropdown in HTML, typing values doesn't work as expected?

Tags: php, html

I am using a drop down containing days of a month (so from 1 to 31).
But when I type 22, it is loading 20.

Below is the code i am using.

```
<select>
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
</select>
```

**What could be the problem here?**

I need the drop down for the guys who want the selecting option. Some users are focusing the drop down using TAB button and just typing the date.

So i need both features.

Comment: Might you share your code to secure you the best answers?

Comment: How are we supposed to give you an answer without seeing the code?

Comment: please post your code

Comment: You can use select2 plugin

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve]) ). We cant help with your code problem without having your code. So please **edit** the question accordingly!

Comment: It's loading `20` because it's **order *first*** of *starting with* `2`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Can we change or override the default feature of drop down list?

Comment: @YeldhoJoy yes, see the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 has a built-in combo box. You create a text input and a datalist. Then you add a list attribute to the input, with a value of the id of the datalist.

To tie a datalist to an input element, give the input element a list attribute and the datalist an id attribute that match. Here’s an example:

```html
<label for="dayofmonth">Day of months:</label>
<input type="text" name="team" id="dayofmonth" list="day_list">
<datalist id="day_list">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
  <option>11</option>
  <option>12</option>
  <option>13</option>
  <option>14</option>
  <option>15</option>
  <option>16</option>
  <option>17</option>
  <option>18</option>
  <option>19</option>
  <option>20</option>
  <option>21</option>
  <option>22</option>
  <option>23</option>
  <option>24</option>
  <option>25</option>
  <option>26</option>
  <option>27</option>
  <option>28</option>
  <option>29</option>
  <option>30</option>
  <option>31</option>
  <!-- etc... -->
</datalist>
```